# Is it possible to set Powershell module name/version without using a manifest?

Tags: powershell

I can see that without a manifest the default module name is set to the .psm1 filename.

But is there a way to set it within the module's code?

Also I would like to set the version in code.

Comment: That is what a manifest is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are importing a binary module then the module version is pulled from the assembly metadata.  However the name is simply the DLL's filename.  For a script module (.psm1), you can't provide this info to PowerShell other than via a module manifest as Ansgar has already pointed out.

BTW you can get at the Name and Version properties of the module from within the module (`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Module.Name`) but those properties are read-only.