# Powershell : Binary Module setting version number

Tags: powershell

Am writing a powershell binary module which is installed by an executable.
On install I copy the binary files into my $env:PSModulePath path and hey presto the auto-loader picks them up and I can start using them.

So far so good.

Question, where does the Module get the version from.

In my case the module has a version of 2.0.0.0 but my DLL has a version of 1.0.1963.0

[image: Get-Module]
[image: DLL Properties]

Based on answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236337/is-it-possible-to-set-powershell-module-name-version-without-using-a-manifest) I had thought that it came from the dll version, but alas that does not seem to be the case.

Can someone help ?

Comment: What attributes applied to your assembly? In particular `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` and `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and search for "Metadata about the module, such as the module version number, the author, and the description".  And [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you get an example for a Module Manifest.

To get the version information of the file, this is useful:

```
(Get-Item -Path "C:\Windows\System32\...").VersionInfo | Format-List
```